Movie about a single father with a daughter who's secretly a serial killer
It was on Netflix. The movie is about a dad being followed around and harrassed by this guy who is a murderer. One day Richard was in a donut shop or coffee shop and this man whacked the cashier with some type of pan. Next I remember Richard tried to help the young man by dragging him to the back of the store to help him and get him out of there, then the killer knocked them both out and Richard wakes up, sees the dead body and screams. Then the murderer stops the car and tells him to help him get rid of the body so they dragged the man under a bridge into this tunnel.
I know that the different characters were Richard (the father), his daughter who plays soccer and a house keeper both living there. The father just lost his wife which is his daughter mom but the cause of her death secretly was her daughter. Another thing after her death her wedding ring went missing because the daughter kept her victims belongings as a souvenir, same with the neighbor which was young boy which was missing and found in her basement and she kept his glasses (which is the reason why lately ants were in their home), but the little girl plays outside with the missing boy's remote control car.
Also the harasser always called Richard to make sure he doesn't think to try anything funny and keep tabs on him. The harasser one day witness the father's girl kill that bird in the park by breaking its wings and enjoying it but when she looked back he caught her attention so it was like they understood. And he can relate to her because she is a child also a secret murderer and he is an adult.

Please don't ask the same question twice. If you have more details to add to your previous one, use the edit button to add them in (as well as some general details you might know about the movie like the approximate year, country etc.)

You're looking for Duress from 2009 with Martin Donovan and Ariel Winter.

Haunted with nightmares of his wife's recent suicide and struggling to mend the relationship with his only daughter, Richard is caught as a witness to the violence of Abner Solvie. He finds himself at the mercy of a charismatic killer and plagued by his involvement in the city's recent murders. As Abner's new found protege, Richard is forced to adopt the mind of his sociopathic mentor in order to protect the one he loves. Richard must decide if he's willing to kill in order to keep his daughter alive.

Everything you said is there. Abner is actually drawn to the daughter, who's secretly a murderer. Here's the trailer:



